# How do I install rubber pins onto a case fan?

Tags: fan

I have the following rubber pins with my new case fan:

[image]

I'm not sure how to install these. They are obvious to install into the case, the rubber pulls easily into the screw hole and stays in place, however the fan they came with they do not seem to fit in the screw holes at all. I put the thin side into the fan and pulled so hard that it actually snapped the rubber, so obviously that is not the correct method.

How do you install these rubber pins into stubborn fans of which they were designed for?

Comment: lube the rubber a bit before pulling them into the fan. Rubber and plastic grip each other quite good, so it needs a little lubrication.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question, and when I emailed them, this is what I got:

> Please refer to following picture that red mark part is through
>   Suscool 81’s mounding holes and blue part is through GD06’s fan slot
>   holes. We suggest you mound those rubber on Suscool 81, then mound
>   whole part to GD06. And please pull those rubber gently to avoid
>   damage when you install them.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I bought a [Zalman fan with silicone pins](http://www.zalman.co.kr/ENG/product/Product_Read.asp?idx=200) with the following instructions (though my fan had no LEDs, thank Linus):

[image: Zalman's instructions for assembling fan]

But it was impossible to mount it like this in my case 
 (Antec Sonata III at the time). The relevant screw holes in the case were dimensioned for regular [6-32 screws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_case_screws#6-32_screw), which already by inspection obviously wouldn't work.

You sa you have the opposite problem: perhaps you are supposed to really have the pins the other way round? It sounds really weird if the pins *included* with the fan does not fit the *fan* itself.

Either

1. put the Dremel to work,
2. do some mediocre half-solution with the pins or
3. just use regular screws.

I went with 3.

Comment: Antec make thumbscrews sized 6-32. generic of course.  It's not so terrible to use them.. maybe they're better than the rubber things, they may come out more easily too. Perhaps antec had those in mind when it designed such a case.

Answer (score 2):

**I put the thin side into the fan and pulled so hard that it actually snapped the rubber**
 I have had that happen here also.  this style only goes through  One (front or back) of the holes in the fan frame.  It is very hard to grab, the style of fan grommet is inflexible , stiff, and is more "rubber" acting than silicon stretchy, and they are to short for making it easy.

Moving it through slower, waiting for it to stretch out , shimmying it around, and (like moab said) lick it :-)  a little saliva*, or some nose oil :-) , or proper wetting and lubrication methods.  If they are warmer temperature, they will also flex a little more. Pre-Flex them too.  I have pulled them through the reverse side with Long nose pliers even, working it slowly.

If I get this style of fan pins with the case or fan , I like to pick up some softer longer ones seperate They can fit looser, but stay softer for longer, and are more reusable.

All of the styles have various stop (low) locations where the frames settle at, but not all of them are designed for the fan (holes) or case that it is packaged with.  They can sit loosly (the silicon ones will fit more loose) and might seem like it is not Mounted well enough, but it still serves to hold it , even in transport, and isolate it from the vibrations conducting to the case as easily.

It is possible, it is just more effort and time, and they will be stiffer years from now, and harder to remove without again breaking them. So get some extras, use screws when you have to, and Join the club :-)   good luck.

Feetnotes:
*licking it can be bad for your health, and Human skin oils are acidic, and will cause things to break down in time faster.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your situation is different, and your case fan somehow takes small screws. So 2 options would be look for smaller rubber screws or try a different case fan. They're not meant to take small screws. Whatever your situation is, compare it to the normal case, pictured below.

Diagram from nexustech who make some

[image: Mounting diagram]

contrast with typical case fan screws, notice they're quite thick

[image: Smaller case screw]

[image: Normal fan case screws]

and Computer cases have holes for big screws
  [image: Computer case]

Answer (score 0):

I would put all four into the case first, then position the fan against them, pulling gently as the fan is pushed into place.

Answer (score -3):

You could also use tape. I have just taped fans before and they are still here to this day. Buy good tape if you don't have the screws.

Comment: How would one tape the fans to the case? One lien answers are generally not welcome here so I ask you to develop. I'm downvoting this mainly because it isn't a solution to the problem proposed (it is a solution if the question was how to attach a fan to a case)